# Java catch exception design and performance

Tags: java, exception

I want to understand something about catching exceptions.

If I don't want my application to crash while an exception occurs and have no idea what exception will be thrown, then my way of handling the exception in the code is something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {

    // all my code to new StarGAte with a lot of threads and classes

} catch (Exception e){

    //Something went wrong (kill the dev!)
    } 
}
```

are there any performance issue in my code with try/catch block?
Is there a better way to handle exceptions?

Comment: The problem here is testing, not performance.  You want a stack trace in test because it shows you exactly where the error is.  When the full app is built, it's OK to have one `catch (Throwable x)` at the very root, so you can capture (and report) any unexpected exceptions.

Comment: Be careful with threads. Exceptions in separate Threads won't be cought by this code. You have to wrap the Thread internals in a simliar try/catch or use a Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler() to catch every Thread exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are they any performance issue with cover all my code with try/catch?

No. If no exceptions are thrown, the exception handling code is never run.

> there is a better way to do design exception handling?

Don't catch `Exception` unless a method you call *actually throws* `Exception`. Catch *specific* checked exceptions, and `RuntimeException` if you want to be sure.

Comment: I am not experience enough to know which exceptions will be thrown. RuntimeException is enough?

Comment: @Smiled_One don't worry, the compiler will tell you if you need to catch a specific exception type: it is a compile-time error if you don't handle an exception that you need to.

Comment: Thank you. I will do it and search for Thread.setDefaultExceptionHandler()

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions should only be used for error handling. As such they should be rarely executed in your code and their performance will be acceptable most of the time.

Here are some tips on handling exceptions taken from my post [Exceptions Guidelines](https://blog.secure-monkey.com/?p=13)

### Don’t catch top-level exceptions

Don’t catch the top-level exception classes such as Throwable, Exception or RuntimeException directly in your API, unless you really know you need to and you are at the very top of your code base (your main method and top level server/daemon code). These exception classes contain many unrecoverable exceptions that can’t be handled safely. This is especially true for the Throwable class which also catches Error exceptions that the JVM might throw such as out of memory exceptions. Catching these exceptions and continuing to run your application may result in data corruption and undefined behavior.

Make sure that your catch() statements are ordered correctly from most specific to most general. You can use multi-catch statements to group exceptions that need the same treatment like logging an error:

```
catch( Exception1 | Exception2 | Exception3 e) {
    logger.log( "Bad Exception: " + e.getMessage(), e );
}
```

Use the common parent if multiple exceptions can be thrown and handled the same way. For example catching IOException will catch automatically FileNotFoundException because it inherits form IOException.

Avoid catching the Throwable class! Bad things will happen when you start catching unrecoverable JVM exceptions.

### Don’t use exceptions for flow-control

It slows down your code and makes it less maintainable. It is considered very [bad practice.](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)